# Replace document title only if not changed by me

Tags: javascript, domdocument

I know that its a weird subject.

I wanna change the `document.title` only if the page (not my code) has changed it.

So I have an observer to watch the title:

```
var target = document.querySelector('head > title');

var observer = new window.WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // console.log('new title:', mutation.target.textContent);

        // Here call my function to replace the title with mine
        // But don't call that function if the title has been changed by me
    });
});
observer.observe(target, { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true });
```

Then I can see each new value. The problem is that when the title is a new one, I want to replace it with my custom value. And I don't know how to avoid an infinite loop.

Consider this process:

1. The dynamic website such as Twitter/GitHub/Gmail is changing the title by "**(1) New mail**".
2. My function is replacing the title by "**[Gmail] (1) New mail**". But I don't want to trigger an infinite loop.
3. The dynamic website such as Twitter/GitHub/Gmail is changing the title by "**(2) New mail**".
4. My function is replacing the title by "**[Gmail] (2) New mail**". But I don't want to trigger an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, your page title has two states :

- changed by the page
- changed by you

A solution would be to store that state and use it within your observer.
For istance, you may use a global variable :

```
var changedByMe = false;
var observer = new window.WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (changedByMe) {
      changedByMe = false;
    } else {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // your code
        changedByMe = false;
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll update this question as soon as I can achieve my goal. To be continued! :)